# Trimming garbage text from end of URL using regex

Tags: regex

I discovered a client has a mess in Google Webmaster tools - hundreds of pages where the site name somehow got appended to the URL's - all obviously creating 404 errors.

Fortunately, the string is always the same. "Website%20Name"

So what I need to do is have:

blog/category/post-name/Website%20Name

be converted to:

blog/category/post-name/

Assuming a little regex code would be the easiest solution.

Have not been able to track down this example - elsewhere.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: What language are you using?  This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.  For example, Perl has the [URI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/) module, and PHP has the [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex:

```
/Website%20Name$/
```